# Is there a feature in tortoisesvn where inserted spaces are not shown to me as changes

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I use TortoiseSVN 1.6.5 as an Apache Subversion client.
Sometimes, when I change something in the source code, I perform not only
the change, but - by inserting spaces in other lines - I bring the commands of a block
in line.

After this, when I want to check my changes with "Show differences as unified diff",
it would be nice to have the feature "Do not show, when spaces have been inserted".

Is there anything to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible to hide if you use the option `Show changes` for your code comparison rather than `Show differences as unified diff`.

[image]

This will bring up TortoiseMerge (unless of course you have reconfigured what programs you use for an editor).

In TortoiseMerge you then have the option of selecting `Ignore all whitespace changes`.
[image]